# Thai, Vietnamese language not supported in Excel

Tags: php, excel, character-encoding

I have created an excel in which it has Thai and Vietnamese language. My problem is that it is showing these characters as question marks.

**My code is below**

```
$worksheet->write($i, 5, iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", html_entity_decode($text)), $mainquest);
```

I have also tried all the other ISO standards. I put ISO-8859-1 for french language support. I also tried the `mb_convert_encoding` but no progress.

Is there any solutions for this?

Comment: which library are you using to generate a file?

Comment: I'm not a PHP user, so this may be a silly question, but if you're using multiple languages, I would expect that you'd just want to use UTF-8 for everything. Why the translation to ISO-8859-1?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. You are right but it's not working for the excel created. So for the french I used the ISO-8859-1 standard and the problem with french language solved. But for the Thai and Vietnamese there is still issue

Comment: @ConstantineUA Spreadsheet-WriteExcel Module is used for Excel creation

Comment: This perl-module: https://github.com/jmcnamara/spreadsheet-writeexcel?

Comment: @ConstantineUA Yes

Comment: The webservers default is utf-8? Your php files are in utf-8? The data source (db, xml) is in utf-8 and the way you fetch the data is utf-8 too? If you store ISO-8859-1 in an utf-8 database you will get into trouble sooner or later. Best thing to do is switching everything to utf-8 no matter what. When there are sources/libraries involved not being able to switch to utf-8 replace them or convert the data as soon as possible on fetch and as late as possible on transfering back to that library/db/xml.

Answer (score 4):

The encoding charset is not the same as French for Vietnamese and Thai

For Vietnamese (Windows)
 - charset=windows-1258

For Thai (Windows)
 -charset=windows-874

so for Thai:

```
$worksheet->write($i, 5, iconv("UTF-8", "windows-874",html_entity_decode($text)), $mainquest);
```

and for Vietnamese:

```
$worksheet->write($i, 5, iconv("UTF-8", "windows-1258",html_entity_decode($text)), $mainquest);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the issue not fully solved. Now the question marks are gone. but the translation is not proper. This is the original text **Tăng số lượng chiết khấu đối với 1 mã hàng hóa (SKU) nào đó** but after translation I go this **Tãng sôì lýõòng chiêìt khâìu ðôìi võìi 1 maÞ hàng hóa (SKU) nào ðó**.

Comment: it should be your font set which is not finding the right fonts for display. can  you try changing the font set to verdana for vietnamese?

Comment: but its working in the html pages. It shows problem with excel created. So I think there is no problem with the font set.

Comment: can you change the encoding to UTF-16 and revert back?

Comment: With UTF-16 everything changes to question mark. So I think that's not the issue

Comment: ok so its issue with font display only and your font set...if you want to display in vietnamese, clear and distinct display of vowels and diacritics is essential..... so an appropriate font for vietnamese needs to consider the position of diacritics....

suggested fonts: 
`times new roman` , `vu Times` ,`DejaVu`, `FreeSans` to name a few

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116442/discussion-between-preethy-and-coolstoner).

Answer (score 1):

If switching the library is an option I'd suggest to use [phpexcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). It is UTF8-based, which means you shouldn't get into trouble with character encoding at all (if everything else is neatly set to utf-8 in your workflow – db,files, webserver). Never had any problems with this library so far, while having generated spread sheets with all kind of special characters.

Comment: Yes will try that too

Answer (score 1):

you must use UTF-8 encoding for this problem

Comment: it's in UTF-8 but the problem is with the excel.